# Change LANG variable in current shell

Tags: centos, locale

On CentOS 8, when I attempt to change the LANG variable to Italian it does not change. Here is an example of what I am doing.

```
LANG=it_IT.UTF-8
```

Then if I do `ls --help` I still shows the results in English.

Thank you.

Answer (score 12):

Several things are required for that to work:

- the `it_IT.UTF-8` locale has to be available on the system. Check `locale -a | grep it`
- the Italian translation for the corresponding application has to be available (for GNU `ls`, typically something like `/usr/share/locale/it/LC_MESSAGES/coreutils.mo` on a GNU system like CentOS).
- the `LANG` variable has to be exported to the environment for `ls` to be able to access it (`export LANG`).
- for the message language setting specifically, on GNU systems, `$LANGUAGE` takes precedence over the `LANG` and `LC_*` variables (unless `LC_MESSAGE`, `LANG` or `LC_ALL` is set to the C/POSIX locale). So if you have `LANGUAGE=fr:en:it`, you'll get French messages if available even if you set everything else to `it_IT.UTF-8`.
- for the message language setting, `LC_MESSAGES` takes precedence over `LANG` and `LC_ALL` takes precedence over everything else (except `LANGUAGE` unless it's `C`/`POSIX` as seen above).

The output of `locale` should give you a summary of the current settings. `env | grep -e LANG -e LC_` should give you a list of locale-related *environment* variables that are currently set.

Answer (score 4):

`LANG` is an old environment variable from the 1980s when Sun Microsystems developed the basics for the current localization.

The variable is still in use, but it is only used as a fallback in case that the other variables from the official standard are not defined.

The search order is:

- LC_ALL used to overwrite all
- LC_MESSAGES and similar for normal use
- LANG If neither LC_ALL nor a locale type specific definition is available.

If you like to overwrite, use the documented LC_ALL.

Comment: You make it sound like `LANG` is deprecated and should not be used. But in fact, to customize their environment, that's still the variable one should set and only touch the other ones if the default provided by `LANG` for that particular setting is not satisfactory (possibly on a per-process basis). And `LC_ALL` only used as last resort, generally as `LC_ALL=C` to override everything for specific tasks to avoid the effects of localisation.

Comment: Since at least 25 years, `LANG` is only used as a fallback.

Answer (score 3):

Try `LC_ALL=it_IT.UTF-8` and `LANGUAGE=it_IT.UTF-8` in addition to `LANG=it_IT.UTF-8`.

Check if your current locale is set up properly with `locale`.

Also check if the `it_IT.UTF-8` locale is available with `locale -a`.

just setting `LANGUAGE=it_IT.UTF-8` was all I had to do to change the text for messages like the ones in `help` or `man` pages. Keep in mind that `LANGUAGE` sets the language(s) for messages where a translation(s) exists. So `ls --help` might not be entirely in Italian.

Answer (score 0):

I could not display icon etc. in `tmux` while using it on Ubuntu.

By using

```shell
export LANG=en_IN.utf-8
```

it solved the problem. Another approach I used to display correctly was by using `tmux -u`.